# Saving and restoring NSMutablearray to NSUserdefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I am writing a app that needs to save and restore nsmutablearrays to populate a table view. The array will save but won't overwrite once i reset everything. i find that the values are combining together and is giving me unreliable averages... code is below. also i have various view controllers that have this lap function...

```
 // code that adds items to table view and saves a version of the array to nsmutablearray
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
                                 initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.DJ.TSTML"];


        [tableItems3 insertObject:TimeString2 atIndex:0];
        // time string is the time as a nsstring
        [tableItems4 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:seconds2]];

        [tableview reloadData];

        [prefs setObject:self.tableItems4 forKey:@"SavedArray3"];
        [prefs setObject:self.tableItems3 forKey:@"SavedArray4"];
        // this is saving to insurer defaults



        NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)tableItems3.count];

        [Commentcount setText:newString];


        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

        NSNumber *average = [tableItems4 valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];

        Average.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:average];


        NSLog(@"Sucess");

        [prefs synchronize];
    } }
```

Restoring the array :

```
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
                         initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.DJ.TSTML"];

// code used to erase current values in the table view and restore from NSUserDefaults
        tableItems3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        tableItems4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [tableview reloadData];


        NSMutableArray *RestoreArray1 = [[prefs objectForKey:@"SavedArray4"]mutableCopy];
        NSMutableArray *RestoreArray2 = [[prefs objectForKey:@"SavedArray3"]mutableCopy];

        [tableItems3 addObjectsFromArray:RestoreArray1];
        [tableItems4 addObjectsFromArray:RestoreArray2];
        if (tableItems3 == nil) {
            tableItems3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            tableItems4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [tableview reloadData];
        NSLog(@"%@",tableItems4);


    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!
My issue to be clear is that every time i save to nsuserdefaults instead of overwriting the previous array it just keeps the old array and combines with the new one

Comment: should update with better formatting and explaining things more .. *in the view did appear: (necessary to restore values and handling the overwriting)* that is kinda vaguely explained with a relaxed tone and not easy of us to really work things out

Comment: thanks, im a little new to asking questions and have included notes @Shubhank

Comment: `NSMutableArray *RestoreArray1 = [[prefs objectForKey:@"SavedArray4"]mutableCopy];
        [tableItems3 addObjectsFromArray:RestoreArray1];

.. then later on         [prefs setObject:self.tableItems4 forKey:@"SavedArray3"];`

how do you expect it to not combine , if you are retrievining and then saving it later

Comment: Thanks, your point brought an idea to me and it worked! i will explain what happened as an answer @Shubhank

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i answered my own question. As someone brought up it was combining because i was retrieving without overwriting it first.  the following code is what worked...

```
 NSString *Clearstring = [prefs objectForKey:@"Clear?"];
// i created a nsstring that when the method for restarting would change accordingly.
//  so when someone would navigate to this view controller this would fire.
// if clear is yes i would prevent the code that controled the restore function from restoring and prepare
//  it if it was needed to be restored again.
        if ([Clearstring isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {
            tableItems3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            tableItems4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            [prefs setObject:self.tableItems4 forKey:@"SavedArray3"];
            [prefs setObject:self.tableItems3 forKey:@"SavedArray4"];
            [prefs setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"Clear?"];
            [tableview reloadData];

        }
        else{
        tableItems3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        tableItems4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [tableview reloadData];

        NSMutableArray *RestoreArray1 = [[prefs objectForKey:@"SavedArray4"]mutableCopy];
        NSMutableArray *RestoreArray2 = [[prefs objectForKey:@"SavedArray3"]mutableCopy];
        [tableItems3 removeAllObjects];
        [tableItems4 removeAllObjects];

        [tableItems3 addObjectsFromArray:RestoreArray1];
        [tableItems4 addObjectsFromArray:RestoreArray2];
        if (tableItems3 == nil) {
            tableItems3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            tableItems4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [tableview reloadData];
        NSLog(@"%@",tableItems4);

        }
    }
```